# How to get MMS recharge done in India? IS MMS still functional for any of the service providers today in India?

Tags: mms

I am working on a legacy codebase in my organization which has MMS services. There's an issue that has recently surfaced and we want to debug it locally. The problem is we are unable to activate MMS balance on Indian SIM Cards i.e. Airtel Service Provider.

Does anyone here know how to activate it? I tried to reach their customer care as well but alas wasn't able to do it.

Does any other service provider today in India provides MMS packs/recharge options?